# t-sql: dense rank that is increased at every occurence of a flag

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ranking, dense-rank

I have a table that has Parent Rows and Children Rows.
The table consists of an increasing sequence, a row indicating whether it is a child or a parent and a code. I need to create ranking (an increasing number) that is increased only at every occurrence of IsParent column (values:0,1).

This is the table that I have: [original table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZXFhl.png)

[image]

This is the desirable result table: [result table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zROvZ.png)
[image]

Comment: You cannot just post your homework and expect someone else to do it. Please include some code you have writte.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DDL and Sample data would be great, however, looks like you want to use a Window Function. This isn't tested with your data, but this should give you the expected output.

```
SUM(IsParent) OVER (ORDER BY [Row Number]
                    ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)
```